# file search high performance program

Tags: java, multithreading, io

I was having one requirement that is I have to write a high performance file search program, the program is supposed to list down all the files and folder that matches the name pattern provided starting from the topmost folder and searching recursively in subfolders.

program can be command line main class with the following input

The top folder to start search . example that is C:\MyFolders
Type of item to search. File or folder or both
Search pattern java regular expression (java.util.regex) are accepted as paatern

example *MFile*.tx? will find UMFile123.txt and AIIMFile.txs'
Timeout (in secs) by which application must return. otherwise it must return with "could not complete operation " message.

I have come up with anoter approach that is..

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.List;

import com.sapient.test.fileSearch.FileSearch;

public class FilesearchMain {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int flag=0;
        System.out.println("Type Item to Search ");
        System.out.println("1 File");
        System.out.println("2 Folder ");
        System.out.println("3 Both");
        System.out.println("0 Exit");

        try{
        BufferedReader readType = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));


        String searchType =readType.readLine();;

        System.out.println("Enter name of file to search ::");

        BufferedReader readName = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String fileName=readName.readLine();


        if(searchType==null && fileName==null){
            throw new Exception("Error Occured::Provide both the input Parameters");
        }
        validateInputs(searchType,fileName);
        FileSearch fileSearch = new FileSearch(searchType,fileName);
List resultList=fileSearch.findFiles();
        System.out.println(resultList);
        }catch(IOException io){
            System.out.println("Error Occured:: Check the input Parameters and try again");
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private static void validateInputs(String searchType, String fileName) 
    throws Exception{
        if(!(searchType.equals("1") || searchType.equals("2") || searchType.equals("3")) ){
            throw new Exception("Error:: Item to search can be only 1 or 2 or 3");
        }
        if(searchType.equals("") || fileName.equals("")){
            System.out.println("Error Occured:: Check the input Parameters and try again");

        }

    }

}
```

the other file is...

```
public class FileSearch {
    private String searchType;
    private String fileName;

    public FileSearch(){

    }
    public FileSearch(String sType,String fName){
        this.searchType=sType;
        this.fileName=fName;
    }

    public String getSearchType() {
        return searchType;
    }
    public void setSearchType(String searchType) {
        this.searchType = searchType;
    }
    public String getFileName() {
        return fileName;
    }
    public void setFileName(String fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }
    public List findFiles(){

        File file = new File("C:\\MyFolders");

        return searchInDirectory(file);

    }
    //Assuming that files to search should contain the typed name by the user
    //
    private List searchInDirectory(File dirName){
        List<String> filesList = new ArrayList<String>();
        if(dirName.isDirectory()){
            File [] listFiles = dirName.listFiles();
            for(File searchedFile : listFiles){
                if(searchedFile.isFile() && searchedFile.getName().toUpperCase().contains(getFileName().toUpperCase())&& 
                        (getSearchType().equals("1") || getSearchType().equals("3") ) ){
                    filesList.add(searchedFile.getName());
                }else if(searchedFile.isDirectory() && searchedFile.getName().toUpperCase().contains(getFileName().toUpperCase())
                    &&  (getSearchType().equals("2") || getSearchType().equals("3") ) ){
                    filesList.add(searchedFile.getName());
                    searchInDirectory(searchedFile);
                }else{
                    searchInDirectory(searchedFile);
                }
            }
        }
        return filesList;
    }

}


Please advise is this approach is correct as per design..!
```

Comment: Was there any reason why you chose not to use `File.listFiles(FileFilter)`?

Comment: @MadProgrammer could you please correct where I am wrong with updated post..!

Comment: @user1577449: he correctly suggested you should probably benchmark a built-in function and see if it's good enough, before you re-invent it yourself.  Here's an example: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/find.html.  Or this:  http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.io/GetFiles.html

Comment: Guys please see my requiorement first..!!and help me ingetting the solution

Comment: @user1577449 we are, but you're going to need to decide what's useful and what's not...

Comment: @user1577449 I'd probably try and reuse your pattern `Pattern fileNamePattern = Pattern.compile(fileNamePatternRegExp);` rather then recreate it each time...see example in answer

Comment: @MadProgrammer could yoy pleaase post the complete code brother,,, thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 if (topFolderOrFile.isDirectory()) {
      File[] subFoldersAndFileNames = topFolderOrFile.listFiles(fileFilter);
```

Where fileFilter could look something like this

```
public class MyFileFilter implements FileFilter{

    public boolean accept(File pathname) {
        return fileNamePattern.matcher(pathname.getName()).find();
    }

}
```

This basically guarantees that the list of files returned will match the criteria in the `FileFilter`

Now, it's semantics in this case, because in order for the `listFiles` method to work, it will still need to iterate over all the files anyway.

You could try maintaining a single instance of the filter, rather then recreating it over each iteration, but you will need to profile the difference between your algorithm and any benefits that this might bring.

On a side note, you could deploy a `Thread` queue of some kind, where each thread is responsible for checking the matches of a given directory and queuing any new sub directories.  Just a thought

**Reusable Pattern**

```
public static void searchFile(String topFolderName, String type,
        String fileNamePatternRegExp, long timeOut) throws IOException {

    long startTimeStamp = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();

    File topFolderOrFile = new File(topFolderName);
    Pattern fileNamePattern = Pattern.compile(fileNamePatternRegExp);

    searchFile(topFolderName, type, fileNamePattern, long timeOut);

}

public static void searchFile(String topFolderName, String type,
        Pattern fileNamePattern, long timeOut) throws IOException {
    //...
}
```

These are the basic changes I've made, but really, you have to decide if they work.

```
public static class PatternFileFilter implements FileFilter {

    private Pattern fileNamePattern;

    public PatternFileFilter(Pattern fileNamePattern) {

        this.fileNamePattern = fileNamePattern;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean accept(File pathname) {

        return fileNamePattern.matcher(pathname.getName()).find() || pathname.isDirectory();

    }

    public Pattern getPattern() {
        return fileNamePattern;
    }
}

public static void searchFile(File topFolderOrFile, String type, PatternFileFilter filter, long timeOut) throws IOException {

    long startTimeStamp = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();

    if (topFolderOrFile.isDirectory()) {

        File[] subFoldersAndFileNames = topFolderOrFile.listFiles(filter);
        if (subFoldersAndFileNames != null && subFoldersAndFileNames.length > 0) {
            for (File subFolderOrFile : subFoldersAndFileNames) {

                if (ITEM_TYPE_FILE.equals(type) && subFolderOrFile.isFile()) {
                    System.out.println("File name matched ----- "
                            + subFolderOrFile.getName());
                }
                if (ITEM_TYPE_FOLDER.equals(type)
                        && subFolderOrFile.isDirectory() && filter.getPattern().matcher(subFolderOrFile.getName()).find()) {
                    System.out.println("Folder name matched ----- "
                            + subFolderOrFile.getName());
                }
                if (ITEM_TYPE_FILE_AND_FOLDER.equals(type) && filter.getPattern().matcher(subFolderOrFile.getName()).find()) {
                    System.out.println("File or Folder name matched ----- "
                            + subFolderOrFile.getName());
                }

                // You need to decide if you want to process the folders inline
                // or after you've processed the file list...

                if (subFolderOrFile.isDirectory()) {
                    long timeElapsed = startTimeStamp
                            - Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
                    if (((timeOut * 1000) - timeElapsed) < 0) {
                        System.out
                                .println("Could not complete operation-- timeout");
                    } else {
                        searchFile(subFolderOrFile, type,
                                filter, (timeOut * 1000)
                                - timeElapsed);
                    }
                }
            }

        }

    }

}

public static void searchFile(String topFolderName, String type, String fileNamePatternRegExp, long timeOut) throws IOException {

    File topFolderOrFile = new File(topFolderName);
    Pattern fileNamePattern = Pattern.compile(fileNamePatternRegExp);

    searchFile(topFolderOrFile, type, new PatternFileFilter(fileNamePattern), timeOut);

}
```

I'd just like to say, here's a fish, now you need to learn to fish ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer..please could you post the complete code as I have done that will be a great help , make my understanding more clear..!Thnaks in advance.

Comment: please post the oplete code as I have done that will make the understanding more clear from starting itself, Thanks a lot